# Firebase Database Security Rule Block Posts

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm trying to prevent my home view from loading posts that are flagged by the user.

I have a data structure as follows:

```
    "reportedPosts" : {
        "HtnULzU0lnZKYva2M2Wepl6N8wE3" : {
            "reported" : true,
        },
        "boX6rtJ98haWVxNoXfSq21maCVU2" : {
            "reported" : true,
        },
    },

    "posts" : {
        "HtnULzU0lnZKYva2M2Wepl6N8wE3" : {
            "details" : "abc",
        },
        "boX6rtJ98haWVxNoXfSq21maCVU2" : {
            "details" : "abc",
        },
        "jSMSkY9rHtdNkXoLrsFmCAXdY9n2" : {
            "details" : "abc",
        },
        "jnFhJbgCjZeJFx0hspObqoskQej2" : {
            "details" : "abc",
        },
        "r6KPesUr1qORfIJke07SloZHeNW2" : {
            "details" : "abc",
        }
    }
```

My Security Rules:

```
      "posts": {
        ".indexOn": "datestamp",
        "$post_id" : {
          // only load posts not reported
          ".read": "auth != null && !root.child('reportedPosts').hasChild($post_id)",
          ".write": "auth != null"           
        }               
      },     

      "reportedPosts" : {
        ".read": "auth != null",       
        ".write": "auth != null"        
      }
```

However I'm getting

> Listener at /dev/posts failed: permission_denied

Can someone help me shed some light?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common stumbling block when designing Firebase databases.  As the docs say, [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/core-syntax#rules-not-filters) so if you make some children entities readable and others not readable, you'll no longer be able to fetch /posts as you'd expect.

A simple solution: When a post is reported, move it from /posts to /reportedPosts so that it not longer exists under /posts.  Then after you've reviewed the post you can move it back under /posts if the post doesn't violate any rules.  That simplifies your rules and allows users to fetch a list of posts without seeing reported posts.

Comment: Why didn't I think of this, this is a great solution!